# Does such a "universal" Haskell type exist?

Tags: haskell

I am looking for a Haskell type **A** with the following property (using exotic GHC extensions is fine with me...): For all traversable **t**, the following two types are isomorphic:

```
forall a. C a => t a -> a
```

and

```
t A -> A.
```

In my specific case, C is the following class:

```
class Floating a => C a where
    fromDouble :: Double -> a
```

In other words, I somehow would like to pull the universal quantification over all types **a** in class **C** into the type **A**, so that a function t A -> A gives me back a function for **all** a. So I guess I'm looking for a "universal" instance of class C in a certain sense...

I have considered all sorts of fancy definitions for **A**, along the lines of

```
newtype A = A (forall b. C b => b)
```

or

```
data A = forall b. C b => A b
```

or

```
newtype A = A (forall t b. (Traversable t, C b) => t b -> b),
```

or

```
data A = FromDouble Double | Plus A A | Tanh A | ...
```

or even

```
data A = A (forall t. Traversable t => t A -> A),
```

and they can all easily be made instances of class C, but they don't have the property I need (or at least I don't see how to get that property from any of my above definitions).

On odd days I am convinced type A simply doesn't exist, on even days I'm convinced of the opposite...

...so any help would be highly appreciated!

---

To give some motivation for my question: I am heavily leaning on [Edward Kmett's ad library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ad) for my [neural networks library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/neural), and in my first attempt, I was using his Numeric.AD.Rank1.Kahn type for automatic differentiation and backpropagation. This led to a nice API, but was less efficient than his *reverse mode*, which unfortunately uses a quantification as in my question for encoding differentiable functions.

I was hoping that I could have the best of both worlds - one specific (abstract) type *plus* reverse mode efficiency.

Comment: Can you ever do anything with `C a => t a` that you can't do with `t a`?

Comment: Do you mean forall a. C a => t a? In that case, the answer is "yes", because you can use the methods of class C to do something with the a's.

Comment: Can you show a concrete example? In your particular case the only method of the class cannot examine existing values.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand your question, but I'm thinking of things like \(x, y) -> tanh x + sin y (for the case where t is the functor taking a to (a,a)), that is - I'm talking about applying the operations of the Floating class to construct my function.

Comment: Oh sorry I somehow didn't pay attention to the `Floating a=>` part.

Comment: @n.m. no worries :-)

Comment: This is tricky, because if you "expand" the newtype, you end up with something equivalent to `t (forall a. C a => a) -> (forall b. C b => b)`. I don't think you can "connect" them without resorting to tricks that would defeat the purpose.

Comment: You need both universal quantification for `a` and for the `a` on both sides of the function to be the same. I don't think that's possible without "communication" at the type level between the two (using a type variable, which would defeat the purpose I imagine).

Answer (score 12):

Let's assume such a "universal" type `A` exists.

`Const ()` is traversable, hence we get an isomorphism between

```
forall a. C a => Const () a -> a
-- and
Const () A -> A
```

i.e. between (since `Const () a` is isomorphic to `()`, and `() -> b` is isomorphic to `b`)

```
forall a. C a => a
-- and
A
```

So, if any `A` exists, it must be isomorphic to `forall a. C a => a`.

Note that this was your first attempt at a solution -- if that does not satisfy the requirements, then nothing will.

---

Now, in your specific case

```
forall a. C a => a
```

roughly means, by definition of `C` (*) [Note: here I am wrongly "forgetting" the `Floating a` superclass, magin the whole argument much more fragile]

```
forall a. (Double -> a) -> a
```

which is isomorphic to `Double`:

```
iso :: Double -> forall a. (Double -> a) -> a
iso x f = f x
osi :: (forall a. (Double -> a) -> a) -> Double
osi f = f id
```

Proving that the above is really an isomorphism is non-trivial -- I think it requires some parametricity as in ["Recursive types for free!"](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/papers/free-rectypes/free-rectypes.txt). (Consequence of Yoneda? ... Comments welcome!)

So -- if there is a solution, for your `C`, it has to be `A ~ Double`, up to isomorphism.

(*) I'm stretching things a bit here. I don't know how to precisely handle Haskell's bounded quantification, so I resort to making the dictionary explicit, even if, I guess, it's not exactly the same.

Comment: Very good point! So if there is a positive answer, then that answer must be forall a. C a => a...
I had been thinking about that type before, and I couldn't see how it would satisfy my property, but of course that's no proof that it doesn't.

Comment: It sounds quite convincing, but I'm not sure your (*) holds. For example, pi is an element of forall a. C a => a (because pi belongs to the Floating class). On the other hand, (fromDouble pi) is also an element. If I understand your line of reasoning correctly, those two elements should be the same, but they are not: Class C also contains floating point numbers with higher precision than Double, so the first element, pi, would have highest precision for each a, whereas the second, "fromDouble", would have the Double precision for all a. So forall a. C a => a has "more" elements than Double.

Comment: @LarsBrünjes I indeed forgot about the `Floating a =>` superclass.